# Unable to display dynamic images - twig + symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

Images are being uploaded via a form and saved in a directory inside my project. I'm trying to display these dynamic images using twig however it's not working.

twig file

```
 {% for photo in image.photos %}
        <img src="{{ asset("#{photo.path}") }}" alt="img">
    {% endfor %}
```

This is what is displayed when I write `asset("#{photo.path}")` in a `<p></p>` tag: /public/uploads/f00e64af69fe3e424ef6aeae7e24e924.png

The images are stored in public/uploads.

services.yaml

```
 uploads: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/'
```

I have `filename` and `path` properties on the `photo` entity.

ImageController.php

```
 $files = $request->files->get('image')['photos'];

            /** @var UploadedFile $file */
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $photo = new Photo();
                $filename = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();
                $photo->setFilename($filename);
                $photo->setPath(
                    '/uploads/' . $filename
                );

                $file->move(
                    $this->getParameter('uploads'),
                    $filename
                );
```

How can I display the photos correctly?

Comment: <img src="{{ asset(' photo.path ') }}" alt="img"> I think you try set width and height for image.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, I tried so many things except for just setting the width and height. @poppies